# Unit Testing Of SharePoint Custom Code with Emulator

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012, unit-testing

I am trying to test my Sharepoint custom code, using Microsoft.SharePoint.Emulator  with VS2012 Premium ( because I have MSDN Premium subscription) I know its officially comes with VS Ultimate version, but somehow I download the dlls :
•   Microsoft.SharePoint.Emulators
•   Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes
•   Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Emulators
When I test my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetABCInformation()
{
using (new SharePointEmulationScope())
{
DataTable dt = new DaoObjects.ABCDAO().GetRequestTriggers();
}
}
```

I got this error I tried a lot but can’t solve this issue.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.2.0.0.0.Fakes, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0ae41878053f6703' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry
>   value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note:
>   There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind
>   failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. Kindly share your opinion
>   about it.

Comment: Try and check the target framework currently selected for the test project? I suspect it is switched to framework 4/4.5. Try to set it back to framework 3.5 and see if that works.

Comment: I tried a lot to switched back to 3.5 but no luck still gets the same error "System.Web.2.0.0.0.Fakes"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NuGet Package Manager to install the Emulators package? If so, that's what I did to resolve it:

1. Change the project's target framework back to 3.5
2. Remove the Microsoft.CSharp reference from the project
3. Remove the Microsoft.SharePoint.Emulators package from the project (via NuGet Package Manager)
4. Re-Add the Microsoft.SharePoint.Emulators package to the project (via NuGet Package Manager)

Et voila, everything works fine again. Hope this helps.